# Why am I getting random symbols with BufferedReader's readline()?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I am trying to read from a text file that visual basic wrote. When I use the readline method that the bufferedReader class gives me, I get random "fluff" at the beginning of the line. I've tried being lazy and just cutting the symbols off with a substring (bad idea), but I really want to understand why I would be getting this and what I can do to prevent it 
Here is the VB Code that pertains to the error:

```
total = CStr(co1) + " " + CStr(co2) + " " + CStr(co3) + " " + CStr(constant) + " "

            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Server 1\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RationalRouteGUI\RationalRouteGUI\res\readWrite.txt", total, False)
```

Here is the text file's text:

```
 5 5 5 5
```

Here is the error I'm given:

```
ï»¿5 5 5 5 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ï»¿5"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at CalcMain.main(CalcMain.java:27)
ï»¿5
ï»¿5
ï»¿5
ï»¿5
```

Here is the code, I'll box the problem area in #'s.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CalcMain {
        public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
                int leadCoeff, secCoeff, thirdCoeff, finCon;
                String total="";
                String[] strFormula= {" "," "," ", " "};
                int[] formula= {1,1,1,1};
                BufferedReader fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Server 1\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\RationalRouteGUI\\RationalRouteGUI\\res\\readWrite.txt"));
            //    PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Server 1\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\RationalRouteGUI\\RationalRouteGUI\\res\\readWrite.txt");
                try {//#############################################################

                    total= fileRead.readLine();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.print(total);
              //####################################################################3
                for(int x=0; x<4;x++){
                    strFormula[x]= total.substring(0,total.indexOf(" ")); //leadCoeff
                    total=cutString(strFormula[x],total);
                    System.out.println(strFormula[x]);
                }

                leadCoeff= Integer.parseInt(strFormula[0]);
                secCoeff= Integer.parseInt(strFormula[1]);
                thirdCoeff=Integer.parseInt(strFormula[2]);
                finCon=Integer.parseInt(strFormula[3]);



                fileRead.close();
        }

        public static String cutString(String in, String total) {
            int index= total.indexOf(in);
            total.substring(0,index);
            return total;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary code.

Comment: Just did, hope it helped

Comment: @SLaks Is having a BOM on every line or before every character standard?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No; his VB code is probably wrong.

Comment: just added my vb code to the main post

Comment: Alright, I found out that VB automatically uses Utf-8 as default for this. I need to change my vb code to use ascii encoding or somehow remove the BOMs